# Casting between interface sublass and superclass when superclass is not implementing interface but subclass is

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting

In the following code

```
abstract class Vehicle { }
class Car extends Vehicle implements LandMover { }
interface LandMover { }
     Car porsche=new Car();
     LandMover lmv;
     lmv = porsche;
     Vehicle vec = (Vehicle)lmv;
```

Shouldnt there be a compiler error in 4th line as there is no relation between class vehicle and Interface LandMover?? and if there isnt  what could be the reason.Thanks!!

Comment: What happened when you try?

Comment: @Kugathasan i tried it doesnt show any compile error and i am a bit confused now with an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler only checks if there is a possible relationship, and there is one:

A `LandMover` could be a `Car`, which in turn IS-A `Vehicle`. Since you promise that this conversion is ok by using an explicit cast, the compiler is happy.

Answer (score 1):

No, since

```
    LandMover lmv = porsche;
```

doesn't declare an object of type LandMover, but refers to an object of type 'Car' via reference 'LandMover'. Compiler knows that this is an object of type 'Car' (note: 'Car' and "Vehicale' are in the same inheritance tree).

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly casting to `Vehicle`, the compiler will not tell you anything. You might just get an Exception at runtime if the relationships finally don't quite work out and you are casting something that is actually not a `Vehicle`

Answer (score 0):

Compilation will be fine with the code you have provided. `lmv = porsche;` is same as saying

```
public class Car extends Vehicle implements LandMover {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        LandMover car = new Car();
    }
}
```

A Car implements  LandMover so you can use it as an polymorphic reference. So no problem so far.

```
Vehicle vec = (Vehicle)lmv;
```

Now you are saying the LandMover(reference) which can very well be a Car is fact a Vehicle. So compiler will not complaint.

**But note after this type cast if you try to call some function on `vec` that is not defined in Vehicle Class(Not even the ones in Car class though infact it is an runtime instance of Car class) compiler will complaint.**

This is because at runtime compiler only checks the class of reference type and if the function that is called is defined(may not be implemented) in it then there will not be any compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any compile errors. This is because a class can implement many interfaces therefore a given 'LandMover' instance can be a Vehicle. However since a class can inherit from a single super class you know that you can't cast a 'java.lang.String' to 'Vehicle' because they don't share a common superclass other than object.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the hierarchy

`Car extends Vehicle`

&

`Car implements LandMover`

For the casting `Vehicle vec = (Vehicle)lmv;` the compiler can check **statically** (compile time), the type of `lmv` which is `LandMover` and which in turn also **CAN** be `Car` (as `Car implements LandMover`). Now as `Car extends Vehicle` the compiler does not complain.

**to Confirm** it, try commenting the code as follows

```
        //Car porsche=new Car();
         LandMover lmv;
         //lmv= porsche;
         Vehicle vec = (Vehicle)lmv; //Compiler error
```

Here, compiler is sure that `lmv` **CANNOT** be `Vehicle` for sure and hence flags error.

Comment: compilation fails due to 'lmv' not being initialized if u set lmv=null it compiles fine.

Comment: It will give runtime exception (Class cast exception) it compiles fine because compiler thinks that there is a possiblity that abstract class vehicle is extended by an another class and as kappil gave the explanation above expilcit casting wont give any compilation error

Answer (score -1):

there will be an error as abstract class can not be instantiated
for more refer to this
[post](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_abstraction.htm)

Comment: he didnt instantiate an abstract class. he instantiated the subclass and used a superclass variable to hold the reference.